# Ubuntu stuck at "Please Remove installation media and close tray and press enter"

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu and after finishing the installation it's stuck at:

> Please remove installation media and close tray and press enter.

I tried installing Ubuntu twice and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried… removing the installation media and pressing Enter?

Comment: What happens when you remove the media and hit enter? Anything? If not, hold you computer's power button. As it restarts, just pop out the disc and it should boot up. (The install already happened as did the boot loader).

Comment: I tried removing the media, i even tried by pressing the "off" button and restarting manually. It doesn't work. After the boot up a set of commands comes up and stucks at the end. I even tried entering some commands but all in vain. My laptop model is Lenovo Ideapad s110.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/282476/ubuntu-stuck-at-pls-remove-installation-media-and-close-tray-and-press-enter

Answer (score 6):

Four possibilities:

- There's a problem on your PC and its partitions. Perhaps you can wipe the area you want to install Ubuntu on and then try again.
- There's a problem with your installation medium. Unlikely, though, because such an issue would have shown up earlier, I would think. You could try making a new one.
- Your computer is unable to know when the tray is closed. Then you have a hardware problem that will probably require replacement. But it sounds unlikely.
- There's not really a problem, and Linux was installed successfully. Just that the Enter thing doesn't work. If you reboot the computer at that moment, can you use Linux? Because this message usually means the installation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same thing. What I did was, pressing the restart button (for 20 seconds)until everything went off, then when my PC restarted, there you go! The fresh uBuntu. I am uBuntu newbie. :)

Comment: This is identical to the fourth option of the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me

1. remove the disk after installation
2. Ctrl + C to leave the message window
3. the computer restarts automatically

I don't know the reason, but I found Ctrl + C help to quit from the window with this message and it restarts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The solution for me was:

-Bring the mouse to the the VM on the top left.
-Right click and bring the mouse to “Power”.
A window will be displayed on the side.

- click Reset.
  That worked for me.